# How to pick data from .xls file in iPhone

Tags: iphone, excel

I have go through the already asked questions on this website but did not get my answer. [This resource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1630.html) says that webview can load the .xls file but I have to get the data from it.

My thinking is converting this file to some XML format, but I have never done that before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your app is jut for learning purposes you could use [xlslib](http://xlslib.sourceforge.net/index.php) to parse the xls file. If you want to publish the app to the store you should know that the library uses the GPL. Apps that use GPL code are not allowed on the Apple App store.

for xls files is harder to convert to xml but for files generated using Excel 2007/2010 (extension .xlsx) it's somewhat easier to do what you want. change the extension from xlsx to zip and extract and parse the xmls contained.